# Drop Down list for content organizer

Tags: content, content-organizer, drop-off-library

In order to make it easy to fill property field I would like a drop down with specific properties to choose from when adding documents to Drop Off Library

To simplify adding of docs in my Drop Off Library I would like to let
users choose needed metadata from a drop down menu. For example, the property to
fill my Content Organizer form needs to have one of lets say 10 different Titles
and in order to get just one of those choices as Title I would like a drop down
menu to choose from. This would make it easy both for me as admin and the users
to get content stored in right place. We use SP 2010 with no AddOns. Is it
possible to get a drop down without involving 3rd part?

Sorry if my english sucks, but I´m not fluent speaking, and chances to get
proper answer seems to be more likely when using english :=)

Per Hansson
Sweden

Comment: I hope this video helps in ur issue: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f4DYD1xvNA